# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.- Error with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.DLL

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 5 version and connecting with Oracle. Details of installed software:
Oracle 12C (12.1.0 version), Client, 12.1.0
2 DLLs which are available in GAC:- 
Oracle.DataAccess.dll (2.112.1.0 and 2.121.2.0)
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll (this DLL is not available in GAC)

However after ODAC installation below folder is created and Oracle.DataAccess.dll & Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll is available with 4.1 version
C:\app\client\MachineName\product\12.1.0\client_1;

On running application when it tries to access database we always get below exception:
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: How is your connection string? What is installed in your GAC? (provide output of `gacutil /l`)

Comment: Connection string is generated dynamically. Oracle.DataAccess.dll (2.112.1.0 and 2.121.2.0) are registered in GAC. When tried to register Dll with version 4, message says successfully added but does not show in GAC

Comment: Then show us an example connectionstring. And show us the GAC, esp. the Policies. You don't provide enough information in order to get any help!